# Нельзя в командную строку передать параметры

Tags: c#, cmd

Тут заметил, случайно, если мы попытаемся в своем приложении запустить командную строку с **любыми** параметрами. То откроется только окошко CMD.
Вот сами проверьте

```
Process.Start("CMD", "ping 1.1.1.1");
```

Но если мы используем Powershell, то все работает.

```
Process.Start("Powershell", "ping 1.1.1.1");
```

Тестировал на разных компьютерах (Windows 7, Windows 10, Windows 2012r2) нигде не работает. Может кто знает в чем дело?

Comment: А зачем CMD писать? ping- это консольная утилита. Так выполните просто Process.Start("ping 1.1.1.1");

Comment: ping для примера здесь дан.

Comment: А вы уверены, что cmd в принципе умеет обрабатывать параметры?

Comment: @АндрейNOP раньше точно умел. Сам такое делал. Зуб даю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, но вы забыли указать соответствующий ключ для CMD

> CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
>       [[/S] [/C | /K] строка]
>
> **/C      Выполнение указанной команды (строки) с последующим завершением.
>
>   /K      Выполнение указанной команды (строки) без последующего завершения.**
>   /S      Изменение поведения после /C или /K (см. ниже)
>   /Q      Отключение режима вывода команд на экран (ECHO).
>   /D      Отключение выполнения команд AutoRun из реестра (см. ниже)
>   /A      Вывод результатов выполнения команд в формате ANSI.
>   /U      Вывод результатов выполнения команд в формате UNICODE.
>   /T:fg    Выбор цвета переднего плана/фона (более подробно см. COLOR /?)
>   /E:ON   Разрешение расширенной обработки команд (см. ниже)
>   /E:OFF  Запрет расширенной обработки команд (см. ниже)
>   /F:ON   Разрешение символов завершения имен файлов и папок (см. ниже)
>   /F:OFF  Запрет символов завершения имен файлов и папок (см. ниже)
>   /V:ON   Разрешение отложенного расширения переменных среды с применением
>           символа '!' в качестве разделителя. Например, /V:ON разрешает
>           использовать !var! в качестве расширения переменной var во время
>           выполнения. Синтаксис var служит для расширения переменных
>           при вводе, что приводит к совсем другим результатам внутри
>           цикла FOR.
>   /V:OFF  Запрет отложенного расширения переменных среды.

Вам нужен один из выделенных ключей, таким образом команда запуска будет выглядеть. например так:

```
Process.Start("CMD", "/C ping 1.1.1.1");
```

Можете параметризовать указание ключа чтобы сама команда оставалась одинаковой для любой оболочки консоли.

Answer (score 2):

Параметры в CMD передать можно и вы это делаете. Вопрос только в том какие параметры принимает и как их обрабатывает этот CMD.

Сравните выдачу `cmd /?` и `powershell /?` и увидите что они умеют.

Иначе, следуя вашей логике, можно написать `winword ping 1.1.1.1` и ждать что Word запустит вам ping.